# What happens to the final voltage of capacitors (v_o) when another voltage source is applied?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, homework

I am just trying to find v_o final, since 40V has been applied to capacitor for a while, I know that it reaches steady state and acts as a Open circuit. When the switch moves to b, I know it's initial voltage will be 40 V but how does the 80 V source come into play as the capacitor charges. Is final voltage 80v -40V = 40V?
[image]

Comment: Think about what would happen if the "a" voltage was 80 V. Then what happens after the time Vo reaches 40 V? How did you get the idea that 80V - 40V is involved in this?

Comment: think of the capacitor as a bucket with a small hole in the bottom ... how far will the bucket fill if you place it in 10 cm deep water? ... what happens if you move it to 20 cm deep water? ... what happens if you move it back to 10 cm deep water?